# Migrating from POP to IMAP, multiple account folders

Tags: email, imap, pop3

I am about to migrate all of my email accounts to using the IMAP protocol instead of the POP protocol. The problem I have is that the folders I currently have in Outlook have email in them from multiple accounts. So for instance I have a folder called 'Enquiries' which includes emails from 'enquiries@company1.com' and emails from 'enquiries@company2.com'

Is there a way to combine folders from multiple IMAP email accounts that are on my server? Or do I have to have separate folders for each account? Can I have one large 'PST' file on my server to hold all of my email accounts?

Additionally, if I open up Outlook on my laptop, will I be able to see all of my emails from the past even if I lose my internet connections? Is this what 'Idle' mode is for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMAP supports sharing. But folders belong to a user. So it's unusual to want to do what you have described.

If you want the mail to appear in the same folder, I'm pretty sure you will need to configure your mail server(s) to direct all incoming mail for those two addresses into the same user/folder.

PST files are not an IMAP thing - they're a proprietary Microsoft thing, so no, you can't do that with IMAP.

As for lost internet connection, this should be straight-forward for you to test. Simply disable your internet and see what happens. Try it with messages and folders that you have and haven't previously opened.
[This Microsoft article about working offline](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/switch-between-working-offline-and-online-HP005242598.aspx) makes me think that you won't be able to view existing messages.

Comment: That is what I thought, just wanted it confirmed. Thank you